# MariaDB Security Script under Debian

Tags: mariadb

Under Debian (10), is it mandatory to run "mysql_secure_installation" after installing MariaDB?

Apart from the root password configuration, don't the other lines already have the suggested default values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes.

Default values will disable

- root access from remote machines
- remove anonymous users
- drop the test database (which can be accessed by anonymous users).

However the word "safe" doesn't mean that your system will be safe. Especially if remote access is allowed, you should consider to use a strong user authentication (e.g ed25519) and to secure your connection via TLS/SSL (require SSL in grant command)